# Showing RAW Form on HTML webpage

Tags: html, forms

I cant figure out how to show my form as plain raw text on my html webpage, it just keeps giving me the form itself on my page but not the raw text code.

```
<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: You mean, escape the special characters in the tags? `&lt;form name="myForm" .... &lt;/form&gt;`. Somewhat more context would also be helpful. Where does this form come from?

Comment: This is the code i need to show on my webpage, so that its not executed and turned into a form.

Comment: I understand, but is this a static page, or is it generated from, say, PHP? If you have a server side script running, it can do the escaping for you. If it's a static piece of HTML you need to do the escaping by hand, or one time using a tool.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the HTML code from being executed use the `&lt;` and `&gt;` symbols to replace `<` and `>`: https://jsfiddle.net/x5704Lw3/

**HTML**

```
&lt;form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
<br>Name: &lt;input type="text" name="fname"&gt;
<br>&lt;input type="submit" value="Submit"&gt;
<br>&lt;/form&gt;
```